# output related to primes

Tags: c, factors

Only the function is written below

Function of prime factors

```
void prime(int x) {
    int i, j;
```

wrote this because it wanted for information but don't have any

```
    for (i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            for (j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    printf("%d", i);
                } else
                if ((i % j) != 0) {
                    printf("%d\n", i);
```

The output should be prime numbers of the number and the repeated prime no.s also should be seen so by mutiplication we get the original number

```
                    goto l;
```

Here the `goto` statement takes out of `if` loop

```
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        l: 
            x = x / i;
        }
    }
}
```

Code seems to be correct and also is giving the prime numbers but is the factors are not repeating itself.

for e.g: `24` output should be `2,2,3` but the output is coming as `2,3`

Comment: This would be a good time to start learning how to use a debugger (like GDB, for example). Also, please try to format your code more consistently.

Comment: Why - "24 output should be 2,2,3 but the output is coming as 2,3"? `24 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3`, i.e. output should be 2,2,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

The `goto` statement is useless, it is exactly equivalent to a `break` statement in your case. It does not *break out of the `if` loop*, it breaks out of the `for` loop, which is exactly what `break` does.

Furthermore, the inner loop is useless: if you divide `x` by `i`, you effectively remove the smaller primes from `x`, and `x % i == 0` will hold only for prime values of `i`.

The problem in the output comes from the fact that you increment `i` even if `x` is a multiple of `i`. Therefore you only print a prime factor once and you do not remove it completely from `x`.

The function can thus be simplified into:

```
void primefactors(int x) {
    int i;             

    for (i = 2; i <= x;) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            printf(" %d", i);
            x = x / i;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The function can be made much faster: you can stop the scan when `i` is greater than the square root of `x`:

```
void primefactors(int x) {
    int i;             

    for (i = 2; i * i <= x;) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            printf(" %d", i);
            x = x / i;
        } else {
            i += 1 + (i & 1);  // skip even numbers
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: The "faster" `primefactors()` has reduced range as `i*i` readily overflows when `i > sqrt(INT_MAX)`.  TBD solution

Comment: Suggest `for (i = 2; i <= x/i;) {` instead.  Try `primefactors(INT_MAX)` to see the effect.

Comment: @chux: I agree `INT_MAX` causes an arithmetic overflow, yet it does produce `2147483647 1` after a longer calculation than usual. `i <= x/i` is much slower for large primes. A quick a dirty fix would be `for (i = 2; (unsigned)i * i <= (unsigned)x;) {`

Comment: "`i <= x/i` is much slower for large primes." Perhaps not.  Good compilers will recognize the `x/i` and nearby `x%i` and emit code that generates both for about the time cost of one of them.  IOWs, code can get `x/i` for free since code needs to do `x%i`.  Of course code could force the issue with `div()`.  YMMV.

Comment: @chux: interesting remark! I shall investigate more... I was expecting that kind of optimisation when both `x / i` and `x % i` were computed one after the other but was very disappointed last time I looked at code generated by both gcc and clang.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. I can add comments if you needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prime_factors(int num) {
    int i = 2;
    while(num > 1) {
        while(num % i == 0) {
            num /= i;   
            printf("%d ", i); 
        }   
        i++;
    }   
}

int main() {
    int num;

    while(1) {
        printf("%s", "Enter the number: ");

        if(scanf("%d", &num) != 1)  
            break;

        // \033[1;31m - changes text color to red
        // \033[0;0m  - resets color back to default
        // It works on Linux, I don't know about Windows.
        if(num <= 1) {
            puts("\033[1;31mThe number must be greater than 1.\033[0;0m");
            continue;
        }   
        puts("Prime factors are:");

        prime_factors(num);

        puts("\n");
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

**Testing:**

```
Enter the number: 24
Prime factors are:
2 2 2 3 

Enter the number: 12
Prime factors are:
2 2 3 

Enter the number: 1000
Prime factors are:
2 2 2 5 5 5
```